Convolution inequality involving a supremum
I would like to prove the inequality $$\Big(\int_k\Big|\int_lf(l)g(k-l)\,dl\Big|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \Big(\int_k\langle k\rangle^s|k|^{2\delta}|g(k)|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\sup_{k'}\Big(\int_l\frac{|f(l)|}{|k'-l|^{\delta}}\,dl\Big).$$ Any regularity assumptions on $f$ and $g$ may be assumed, and where $s$ is some positive constant (probably from using the Sobolev embedding).
Starting with $$\Big(\int_k\Big|\int_lf(l)g(k-l)\,dl\Big|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\Big(\int_k\Big|\int_l\frac{f(l)}{|k-l|^\delta}|k-l|^\delta g(k-l)\,dl\Big|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \Big(\int_k\sup_{k'}\Big|\int_l\frac{f(l)}{|k'-l|^\delta}|k-l|^\delta g(k-l)\,dl\Big|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
I get stuck as I can't use Minkowski to exchange the $k$ and the $l$ integrals as I have a supremum in the way?
But if I instead do Minkowski first, then $$\Big(\int_k\Big|\int_lf(l)g(k-l)\,dl\Big|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \int_l |f(l)|\Big(\int_k|g(k-l)|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\,dl=\Big({\int_l|f(l)|\,dl}\Big)\Big(\int_k|g(k)|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ then I have no way of getting the $|k|^\delta$ moments which is the aim of this exercise.

What happens if you take the supremum afterwards? First use Minkowski, then take the supremum?

@stange I made an edit.

What is $\langle k\rangle^s $ ?

@RyszardSzwarc I don't know if it is needed, but $\langle k\rangle :=(1+|k|^2)^{s/2}$ and is used for example to go from $L^1$ to $L^2$ by Cauchy--Schwarz

I was not able to prove the exact inequality as above but this suffices for what I was looking for.
Starting with Cauchy--Scwharz in $l$,
$$\Bigg(\int_k\Big|\int_lf(l)g(k-l)\,dl\Big|^2\,dk\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq\Bigg(\int_k\,\Big[\int_l\frac{f(l)}{|k-l|^{2\delta}}\,dl\Big]\int_l\frac{f(l)}{|k-l|^{2\delta}}|k-l|^{4\delta}g(k-l)^2dk\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq\sup_{k'}\Big[\int_l\frac{f(l)}{|k'-l|^{2\delta}}\,dl\Big]\Big(\int_k\int_l f(l)|k-l|^{2\delta}g(k-l)^2\,dldk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sup_{k'}\Big[\int_l\frac{f(l)}{|k'-l|^{2\delta}}\,dl\Big]^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\int_lf(l)\,dl\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\int_k|k|^{2\delta}|g(k)|^2\,dk\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
